# Multiple Forms in One HTML file (but on multiple pages)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm working on a project where, on the client side, the user would have to fill out an online survey and on the server side, the data is stored in a database. The survey itself consists of multiple pages, where each page is a form. So essentially, that single online survey consists of multiple forms.

I'm picking up right after where the person who created the online survey left off. The way she had it done was something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="survey.css">

    <script>
      
      // when the user clicks the button on the first page, he/she is brought to a new page where the stuff inside the function is displayed
      function Q2(){
            document.getElementById("Q").innerHTML = "does something...<button type='button' onclick='Q3()'>Next</button>";
        
      // same deal here, stuff in this function are displayed in a new page  
      function Q3(){
            document.getElementById("Q").innerHTML = "does something...<button type='button' onclick='Q4()'>Next</button>";
        
      // same as the two functions above
      function Q4(){
            document.getElementById("Q").innerHTML = "does something...<button type='button' onclick='Q5()'>Next</button>";
        
      // keeps going until the last question
        
    </script>
    </head>
<body>

<!-- this is the first page when the file is opened -->
<h1>Meeting 1</h1>
    <p id="Q">Some text...<br><input type="text" name="tweet" style='height: 50px;width: 500px;'><br><br>
      <button type="button" onclick="Q2()">Next</button> 
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to store things in a database, and that's where things started getting confusing for me. I've done research online and I'm sure that rather than having each page/form be a function (Q2, Q3, etc.) in JS, it would be better to have each page be its own HTML form and send the data to a PHP file, where the connection and storing data to the database happens.

**WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN:** Is it possible to have all the forms be written/stored in a single HTML file, and at the same time, have each subsequent form be displayed on the next page? If that's not possible, what should I do?

Here's some test code I created (currently displays both forms on the same page, which isn't what I want):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN”
  “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml” xml:lang=”en” lang=”en”>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="survey.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <h1>Meeting 1</h1>    
 <form name="form1">
      <!-- Some HTML code goes here -->
      <button type="button">Next</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <form name="form2">
      <!-- Some HTML code goes here -->  
      <button type='button'>Next</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Form tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) doesn't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: You might be better off with the original version with functions. All you have to do is send the filled in data to some server-side php by ajax call inside the next function's body.

Comment: **vacsora:** but for each "document.getElementById("Q").innerHTML =",  the HTML code that comes after it are enclosed in quotation marks, making it one long string. If I wanted to insert AJAX right before the "Next" button, wouldn't that break the flow of the sentence? Sorry if I'm not making sense!

Comment: Use different `action=` or add a `value=` on a button to recognize the form. Or a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

you could use actually simply use jQuery and CSS to put all your forms in the *same place* one behind the other. However you'd have to use **ajax** to put the form info into your database. Do it as such:

```
$(".step1").show();
$(".step2").hide();
$(".step3").hide();

$(".step1").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       url : 'submission1.php',
       data : { name : $(".step1").children("input[name='username']") },
       method : 'POST'
   })
   .done(function(data)
   {
       $(".step2").show();
   });
});

/** Repeat the same process with step 2 and 3 **/
```

Then your CSS could be as follows ***Your forms must be in a parent container***:

```
.step1
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

.step2
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}

.step3
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Complete example here: https://jsfiddle.net/LkjmL43h/3/

Comment: What language is the first code you wrote above? Should that be placed with the HTML file that contains the online survey? And could you explain what you meant by "Your forms must be in a parent container"? Thank you!!

Comment: The language I wrote the code is JavaScript using the jQuery framework (www.jquery.com), I will add the HTML as well shortly so you know how it would be used

Comment: Everything was put into a fiddle

Comment: **CristianHG**, thank you so much for your help & the example!! But ahhh it's not working for me. I tested it out, and 2 forms are displaying at the same time. I put the jQuery stuff in the same HTML file as the online survey, but enclosed them in a <script> tag, right after the online survey code. Did I do it right?